# I can't read from the environment variable (aws-lambda in Go)

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, dynamo-local

I want to test AWS Lambda in local environment using DynamoDB Local and SAM CLI.
I create a simple user db table(id, name) and I'm trying to get the data.

I run "sam local start-api --env-vars test/env.json". When I access "http://localhost:3000/users/1", an error occured. Error message is below. I can't understand what this error message means. How do I fix this error?

```
{
  "errorMessage": "InvalidParameter: 1 validation error(s) found.\n- minimum field size of 3, GetItemInput.TableName.\n",
  "errorType": "ErrInvalidParams"
}
```

This is my code.

```
func handler(request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    // Environment variables
    endpoint := os.Getenv("DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT")
    tableName := os.Getenv("DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME")

    // Request
    id, _ := request.PathParameters["id"]

    // DynamoDB
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())
    config := aws.NewConfig().WithRegion("ap-northeast-1")
    if len(endpoint) > 0 {
        config = config.WithEndpoint(endpoint)
    }

    db := dynamodb.New(sess, config)
    response, err := db.GetItem(&dynamodb.GetItemInput{
        TableName: aws.String(tableName),
        Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            "Id": {
                N: aws.String(string(id)),
            },
        },
        AttributesToGet: []*string{
            aws.String("Id"),
            aws.String("Name"),
        },
        ConsistentRead:         aws.Bool(true),
        ReturnConsumedCapacity: aws.String("NONE"),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{}, err
    }

    user := User{}
    err = dynamodbattribute.Unmarshal(&dynamodb.AttributeValue{M: response.Item}, &user)
    if err != nil {
        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{}, err
    }

    // Json
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(user)
    if err != nil {
        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{}, err
    }

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        Body:       string(bytes),
        StatusCode: 200,
    }, nil
}
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfNF9.png)

Comment: It looks like length(tableName) must me more than 3

Comment: @bayrinat I tried some patterns. First, I hard-code "User" for tableName. Then `"ResourceNotFoundException Requested resource not found\n\tstatus code: 400, request id: RPFTVHFR7B85093FEI0VRN63V3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG"" occured.` Second, I hard-code "http://localhost:8000" for endpoint in addition to tableName. Then this message is appeared. `Function 'UserGetFunction' timed out after 5 seconds` I haven't solved the problem yet.

Comment: I know some things. First problem was because the value could not be read from the environment variable. This problem has not been solved yet. Second problem was because "localhost" expression. Rewriting "localhost" to "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" worked fine.("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" is ip address of my laptop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's been resolved.

**First Problem: can't read from the environment variable**
This was because the indent size deviation of template.yaml. Category "**Events**" and Category "**Environment**" had to be in line.

**Second Problem: error with "Function 'UserGetFunction' timed out after 5 seconds"**
This was because "localhost" expression. Rewriting "localhost" in env.json to "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" worked fine.("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" is ip address of your laptop)